# Analyzing runtime of a nested for loop

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, computational-complexity

```
// assume n is a power of 5
for (int i=1; i<n; i=i*5)
    for (j=i; j<n; j++)
        sum = i+j;
```

I am supposed to find out how many times each line of code runs. I was told that I would need to use the geometric series formula to find the total run time.

I know that the first line of code `for (int i=1; i<n; i=i*5)` runs $\log_5n$ times because the values of `i` are $5^0,5^1,5^2, ... , 5^k$ and this is equal to $k=\log_5n$.

The runtime of the inner for loop `for (j=i; j<n; j++)` decreases by $1$ after each iteration. I found that on the first iteration this loop runs `n`times. On the second iteration the loop runs `n-4`times, on the third it runs `n-124` times.

I think the sequence is $n, (n-4), (n-24), (n-124),...,(n-5^k +1)$
each term can be found by the formula $n-5^k+1$ where $k$ is the kth term in the sequence (starting from $0$).

How do I find the sum of this sequence using the geometric series formula?

I wasn't sure what upper bound I would use for the summation so I used an arbitrary variable `m`.

$\sum_{k=0} ^{m}n-5^k+1 = (n+1)\dfrac{1-5^{m+1}}{1-5}= (n+1)\dfrac{1-5^{m+1}}{-4} $

Is this the correct approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You correctly found that the `j<n` test in the second line is executed a total of
$$\sum_{h=0}^m (n-5^h+1)$$ 
times, for some integer value of $m.$
This is *almost* the formula for the total number of iterations of the inner loop
(the number of times the third line runs), which is
$$\sum_{h=0}^m (n-5^h)$$ 
for the same value of $m.$
That's because the first inner loop
actually executes only for the values $1,2,3,\ldots,n-1,$ which is a total
of $n-1$ iterations, not $n,$
and similarly it does not execute when $j$ is $n$ at any other time.

(I changed $k$ to $h$ in the summation because you already used $k$ to mean
something else, $k = \log_5 n,$ and while it is technically permissible
to reuse $k$ as the variable of summation in this case, it is confusing.)

There *is* a particular value of $m$ that you should use.
Consider what the value of $i$ is on the last iteration of the outer loop,
and how that relates to your variable $k.$

Notice that if $k=\log_5 n$, then $5^k = n.$ The outer loop will not actually
call the inner loop for $i=n$ because of the condition $i<n.$
So you have iterations for $i=5^0,5^1,\ldots,5^{k-1}.$
(In this particular problem it turns out the answer is the same whether we execute
the inner loop for $i=5^k=n$ or not, but in general if you want to count an exact number
of operations then it's advisable to keep track of when each loop ends.)

So we can conclude that the last value of $h$ for which we need to add a term of
the sum is $h=k-1,$ which counts the last $n-5^{k-1}$ iterations of the inner loop.
The sum that counts the number of times the third line runs is therefore
$$\sum_{h=0}^{\log_5n-1} (n-5^h) = 
\left(\sum_{h=0}^{\log_5n-1} n\right) - \left(\sum_{h=0}^{\log_5n-1} 5^h\right).$$
Now we can see a geometric series in the result, and the other part of the
result is even easier to evaluate.

Comment: When $i = 5^{k+1}$, `j` iterates through the values $5^k -1, 5^k, 5^k +1, ..., n$ How would I find the sum of this? Is this value needed in order to find the summation?

Comment: Where did $5^{k+1}$ come into this? Also, you don't need to _sum_ the values that $j$ actually takes, just count them. You were adding _almost_ the correct sequence, you were just off by $1.$ The last value of $j$ for which `sum = i + j` executes is always $n-1,$ never $n,$ so you should be adding $(n-1)+(n-5)+(n-25)+\cdots+(n-5^{k-1})$ rather than $n+(n-4)+(n-24)+\cdots.$

Comment: I think I was off by $1$ because I was calculating the runtime for the inner for loop, not `sum = i + j`. Since the inner for loop has to check it's condition for failure for every iteration of `i`, wouldn't I have to include it in the calculation? I also meant to say $5^{k-1}$ which is the last time `i` executes it's code.

Comment: Good point: `j++` and `j<n` each execute one extra time compared to `sum = i + j`. The question did say we had to count how many times _each line_ executed, so take my sum for the last line and your sum for the second line. In evaluating your sum it may help to write $n+1-5^h.$ You can then sum the $n+1$ and the $5^h$ separately.

Comment: Oops, that's $n - 5^h + 1$ times we execute `j<n`, but `j++` is still done only $n - 5^h$ times; but `j=i` is also done once. It's a little unclear what is meant by "how many times this line runs" when the line is a control statement with multiple sub-parts.

Comment: I think my professor allows us to treat each line as one component. What I meant earlier was with a condition `i<n`, if `i` started at $0$ and was incremented once each time. The total runtime of that line would be `n+1`. The loop itself has a runtime of `n+1` because it also has to run once to know when it fails. The contents of that for loop would run `n` times because we don't count the fail condition of the loop.

Comment: But $i$ does not start at zero. Neither does $j$ ever start at zero in this program. $i$ starts at $1,$ and $j$ starts at $i.$ Don't compute the runtime for a program different from the one given!

Comment: I know, I was giving an example on why I was off by $1$. I included the run time of the fail condition because that was done in class. Using this, would my original approach be correct?